# Adobe AIR (html/javascript): navigateToUrl's window parameter not working

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, air

have a problem navigating to a Url in the default browser in an Adobe Air project (html/javascript).

`air.navigateToUrl(request, windowName)` launches the browser and displays the page, but it displays a new tab for every request.

Here is a very simple example of the main page in a new Air application that reproduces the problem:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>navigateToURLTest</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/air/AIRAliases.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>      
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:air.navigateToURL(new air.URLRequest('http://www.adobe.com'), 'TestWindow');return false;">Same Tab</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I open the url in the same window/tab?

Comment: I looks like a bug in Air, but there must be a work-around.  Any idea

Answer (score 0):

You should have both of your anchors to have the same target specified:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>navigateToURLTest</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/air/AIRAliases.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="testp"
            onclick="javascript:air.navigateToURL(new air.URLRequest('http://www.adobe.com'), 
            'TestWindow');return false;">New Tab</a>
        <br />
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com" target="testp"
            onclick="javascript:air.navigateToURL(new air.URLRequest('http://www.adobe.com'), 
            'TestWindow');return false;">Same Tab</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

If no window with name `"testp"` is opened in your current list of tabs, it will open a new tab, and if you already have it, then it will be changed.

Comment: @rekaszeru: thanks.  I added the _blank target just to show the two possible methods available in Air (no target specified defaults to _blank).

Comment: @rekaszeru: The problem occurs when I click multiple times on the anchor with the named window parameter. (Or in your code when I click on both links, I get two tabs opened.

Comment: so you must specify every time the target, and this way you'll be assured that the link will be opened in the same tab (window). what problem occurs?

Comment: The problem is that the link always opens in a new window.  Tried it with Chrome as the default browser and with IE as the default browser.  I tried it debugging Air (in Aptana studio), but also after a full installation of the HTML/Javascript Air application.  The Adobe docs state that both "_self" and a named window parameter can be used.  But it is the named window parameter that does not work.

Comment: So your problem is that a new window is opened instead of a new tab? That should be corrected in the browser settings. Otherwise the code above (even when changing the `href` attributes to "#") does what it should, searches for the 'testp' tab/window, and opens its link inside of it.

Comment: @rekaszery: Hi again.  The problem is that a new tab is opened for every click.  With your code or mine.  (I know that if I that HTML in a web page, it would work; however it is the source of the main Air window).  So the code does not what it should.  It does not search for a previousely opend window/tab but opens a new tab every time the link is clicked.  It drives me nuts!

Comment: I see. could you please share the code of your main application's relevant parts, to have a look?

Comment: The code I posted is all the code there is: I created a new Air project (html/javascript) in Aptana studio and just added the two href's to the mainpage's body.  That's all.

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com"), '_self');
```

applied to your code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>navigateToURLTest</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/air/AIRAliases.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="air.navigateToURL(new air.URLRequest('http://www.adobe.com'),'TestWindow');return false;">Same Tab</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Please notice two things,
rekaszeru has added a link in the href ( which should not be there... same with target= )
second, the onclick event does NOT need the "javascript:"

Comment: @Rephael: that is exactly what I do.  Does that work for you?  Not for me.  (Debugging in Aptana Studio).

Comment: I just created the same Air application in Flash Builder (ActionScript).  Same problem.

Comment: Just a comment, i would have href="javascript:void();" since i hate the hash symbol ( it jumps to top of page )

Comment: Did you notice i have changed my answer?

Comment: @Rephael:  Sorry, did not notice it.  I wish StackOverflow sent immediate notifications!! (And wake-up calls).  I'll try it asap.  One thing though, the "_self" ref did work for me too; it's the windows param that didn't.  But I'll try the "applied to your code part".

Comment: @Rephae: I copied your code, no success.  Did that work for you in an AIR project?

Comment: Rephael,  was this with Air 2.6?  This is driving me nuts.   I tried it in Air/Flex instead of Air/Html, but even in Flex no joy:  opens a new window; same code...

Comment: let me just understand,
the first click will open a new window.
all other clicks in the original window should open up in the same window.
if you run the same app in the new window, it will open a new window ( since it does not "see" itself as a window )
is that what happens?

Comment: @Rephael :  >>the first click will open a new window. all other clicks in the original window should open up in the same window<<   Yes, that is correct.   >> if you run the same app in the new window<<  I do not run the app in a window; it's an Adobe AIR app, so it runs in adobe Air's runtime, and that has it's own WebKit browser.

Comment: can you try to replace the onclick with this one ?
onclick = "function(){   air.navigateToURL( new air.URLRequest('http://www.adobe.com') ) ,'TestWindow'} ;return false;"

Comment: @Rephael : if I put function(){ air.navigateToURL(new air.URLRequest('http://www.adobe.com'), 'TestWindow');  return false;}; in the onclick, the browser opens, but does not display the page (it displays the Air window).  Thanks again for helping me out.

Comment: @Rephael : I also tried putting the function in the head section.  The browser displays the page, but again in a new tab on each click....